# Script to unlock and lock monitoring screens remotely

Tags: windows, remote

We have several Windows 7 machines that are used for monitoring screens on the wall (one machine per monitor).

We have to log these in every morning and lock them over night. This is a tedious process and I am looking to try and automate this.

We currently use VNC to connect to the machines individually as RDP doesn't allow us to view the screen using the VGA connection also. I have tried using `mstsc /console` but this doesn't display the console on the monitors.

I have [seen](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315249.aspx) ways of locking the machine remotely, so should be able to do this with PsExec. However I have heard that this may not be the best way to do this; [Throwing garbage on the sidewalk: The sad history of the rundll32 program](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683/). Is there a better way? Also, I cannot find a way of logging the machine on via a script and being able to view the console on the monitor, is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to lock them at night?

Comment: Boss says they need to be for security reasons. I guess because if they get compromised in the at night there is no one to notice something weird going on and at night the lock adds an extra password, providing they are attempting to gain access via VNC,

Comment: Poor answer I know, but it boils down to, my boss says I have to so I have to.

Answer (score 0):

[PSSutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897541?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) might come in handy; something like

```
psshutdown \\myComputer -l
```

Comment: u r welcome, mark my answer if you like to ;)